# What does [1] do on function?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need an explanation on below js code,

```
function getURLParameter(url, name) {
  return (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)')
  .exec(url)||[,null])[1];
}

var id = getURLParameter(url, 'id');
console.log(id); //1

// let say the example of url is 
// index.php?id=1&user=xxx
```

What is `[1]` on the return statement use for?

I am confuse on how does it get the value of 1 for the id

Comment: It accesses the second element of the array.

Comment: You can do the debugging and see yourself.

Comment: The return value of `.exec(url)` is probably an array. In case `.exec(url)` doesn't return an array, I think `||[,null])` defaults in `[,null]` as the array to index into, and finally the `[1]` indexes into whatever array is the value being operated on at that point. So you should either get the second element of the array returned by .exec(url) or a null if .exec(url) returned a null. But as @Batman25663 said, you should verify by debugging.

Comment: ... and that second element is probably the parameter section of the url as specified by the regex pattern. Debug it by splitting the whole expression into parts. You can then take a look at the interim results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`RegExp.prototype.exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) returns an array including the matches of the regular expression (or `null`).

`[1]` just accesses the second element in that array — in this case the value of the capturing group in the regular expression.

It's equivalent to:

```js
function getURLParameter(url, name) {
  var regexp = new RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)');
  var result = regexp.exec(url); // array containing the full string of 
                                 // characters matched, the value of the
                                 // capturing group and the end anchor
                                 // (or null)
  if (Array.isArray(result)) {
    return result[1];
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Good that you also provided this non-compact equivalent view of the code. Far more easy to understand, will help OP a lot I think.

Comment: Array of 3 elements, not 2. The full match (0), the id value (1), and the end anchor (2)

Comment: @Tezra, you are perfectly right. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @PeterMader Thanks for the explanation and also for those who help :)